# Query for build at runtime according to program condition

Tags: php, mysql

What points should be kept in mind while writing queries as under?

$sql=" And two=2";

$sql.=" And three=3";

$sqlquery="select * from".$sql;

I want to make complex queries like the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better add `where 1=1` into your main query. This way you could or could not have any number of AND-joined conditions.

Like this:

```
$base_query = 'select * from table where 1=1';
$base_query.= 'and two = 2';
$base_query = 'and three = 3';
```

**UPDATE:** Doctrine ORM style quering:

```
//$em is instance of EntityManager
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('u')
  ->from('User', 'u')
  ->where('u.id = ?1')
  ->orderBy('u.name ASC');

//you could add any part of query later
$qb->andWhere("u.name = 'John'");

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$result = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: I like to add variables also and make update queries also..m having difficulty in making them

Comment: You'll have a hard time trying to generalize building select and update queries. I'd suggest you to have a look at some ORM, like Doctrine. It's more complex than just writing plain SQL at first, but it is MUCH simplier to maintain it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185358/simple-php-orm.
Personally, I would recommend Doctrine ORM: http://www.doctrine-project.org/

Comment: What do think which style is better for writing queries?

Comment: 2.write sql query first and then fetch data or 3.ORM style

Comment: I don't get what do you mean. For fetching data - see http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php, especially MySQLi_Result class. For ORM, I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: I just need to create a query to make a resource id for mysql_fetch_array($sql)

Comment: So, I wana know, which is faster among thwe above three styles

Comment: Faster - plain SQL. Wiser, more maintainable and robust - ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I personally preffer to do that with arrays something like that:

`$where = array();
$where[] = 'Two = 2'
$where[] = 'Three = 3';
$sql = implode(' AND ', $where);`

Other option which i think is better to use some database absraction class / active record

Regards.